# I don't want to use pointers but compiler is saying expression must have pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was using just 1D arrays in a simple program, without using pointers. And yet, in case 1, where I trying to get the size, I get a compiler error saying expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int". I don't know why, can anybody help?

Here's the code:`

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()

{
    const int size = 100;


    int code[size];

    int size[size];

    int quantity[size];

    float price[size];

    int numItems = 0;

    do
    {


        int choice;

        cout << "Please select an option:" << endl;

        cout << "[1] Add a new item to the inventory" << endl;

        cout << "[2] Remove an item from the inventory" << endl;

        cout << "[3] Update the quantity of an existing item" << endl;

        cout << "[4] Update the price of an existing item" << endl;

        cout << "[5] Display the current inventory and the total value of the inventory" << endl;

        cin >> choice;



        switch (choice)

        {

        case 1:

            if (numItems < 100)

            {

                cout << "Enter the code: \n";

                cin >> code[numItems];


                cout << "Enter the size: \n";

                cin >> size[numItems];
```

here is the problem int he cin >> size[numItems]

```
                cout << "Enter the quantity: \n";

                cin >> quantity[numItems];


                cout << "Enter the price: \n";

                cin >> price[numItems];

                numItems++;

            }
```

Comment: What do you think `size[numItems]` should mean?

Comment: You may find further inspiration in [Simple Text Menu Implementation](https://pastebin.com/5kpfTUnX) a similar text menu setup with authentication system. The credentials can be found in the initializers in `main()`.

Comment: That code looks completely confused about `size`.

Comment: This code won't even compile from the fifth actual line of code down, so there's really no point discussing pointers! Start with the first error you get, not with a later one.

Comment: What is this `int size[size];`?

Comment: @Quimby a syntax error.

Comment: @user2357112 interestingly,  the C++ standard allows you to use `size[numItems]` and `numItems[size]` interchangeably, if size would be defined only once and as an array ;-)

Comment: Normally, the compiler should have said  that there is a problem for `int size[size];` .  Please solve the error messages one after the other, starting with the first, because some other irrelevant errors may be caused by that first one.

Comment: ok, I'll decleare size of array MAX_SIZE

Comment: Hint: `std::array` & `std::vector`. Forget that C-style arrays exist in the language.

Comment: Your compiler has issued multiple diagnostics (i.e. reported multiple errors in your code).   You asked about the LAST diagnostic.    Generally speaking, when a compiler issues multiple diagnostics you need to address the FIRST one first - and you find that by scrolling up rather than looking at the bottom/lowermost error on screen.   The reason is that, after *any* error, compilers don't completely recover before continuing and become more and more confused as they encounter more code errors.  Eventually, when there are enough reported errors, the error messages become gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

You have a variable named `size`, and another named `size`.
I doubt that's what you were looking to do. I would look a bit closer, its not written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Redefining an name halfway through the function is not a great idea.

```
const int size = 100;  // Here size is an int


int code[size];        // ok, fine

int size[size];        // now size is an array?

int quantity[size];    // which size is used here?
```

Comment: _`// now size is an array?`_ Well, wouldn't an "answer" require, to tell why it's not, and how that code could be fixed??